# Why won't my prototype work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, oop, prototype

My `alert("No money")` works fine but how come my `alert("works!")` won't work?  The errors don't make sense to me either because I feel like what I've written is syntactically correct.

Thanks for taking the time to read :D

Here is my gameTime.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WOMP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gameTime.css">
</head>     
<body>
    <form class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" name="formHandler" id="handle">
        <div id="allFields">
            <div class="moveUsername">
                <h1>(All numbers inputted will be assumed that it's in dollars)</h1>
                <label for="usr">What's your annual salary?</label>
                <input type="field" class="form-control" id="salary" placeholder="What's your annual salary?" required="required">  
            </div>

            <div class="ageMovement">
                <label for="usr">How much do you spend every month on bills?</label>
                <input type="field" class="form-control" id="monthlyBills" name="ageChecker" placeholder="How much do you spend every month on bills?" required="required">
            </div>

            <div class="emailMovement">
                <label for="usr">How much do you spend when going out?</label>
                <input type="field" class="form-control" id="goingOut" name="emailChecker" placeholder="How much do you spend when going out?" required="required"> 
            </div> 
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="fin.isSalaryZeroOrLess()">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gameTime.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my gameTime.js

```
  function Finance(salary, fixedExpense, variableExpense) {
    this.salary = salary;
    this.fixedExpense = fixedExpense;
    this.variableExpense = variableExpense;
    this.isSalaryZeroOrLess = function() {
        var s = parseInt(document.getElementById("salary").value);

        if(s <= 0) {
            alert("No money");
        }
    }
}



 Finance.prototype.greaterThan = function() {
    var s = parseInt(document.getElementById("salary").value);
    var userSalary = s / 12;

    if(userSalary < 30000) {
        alert("works!");
    }
 }

    var fin = new Finance(1000,1000,1000);
```

Here are the errors:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'greaterThan' of undefined
    at gameTime.js:14
gameTime.html:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSalaryZeroOrLess' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (gameTime.html:28)
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the first error. There’s a `}` missing for `Finance.prototype.greaterThan = function() {`.

Comment: @Xufox I caught that right after posting this question.  I fixed it, but it still won't work :(

Comment: @Xufox When I caught the error & fixed it, I checked my console for any other errors, nothing showed up.  There are no errors in the console and yet my `greaterThan()` prototype won't work.

Comment: I don't see any usage of `greaterThan` in your code. It seems that you didn't post all relevant code

Comment: Note: `onclick="fin.isSalaryZeroOrLess()"` is a bad practice. your code will fail if script is loaded after DOM *which should happen*. Also it relies on global scope. I'd suggest using `.addEventListener`

Comment: I posted everything in my `.html` & `.js` files.  How do create a usage for  `greaterThan` so that it can work?

Comment: @chompy please try to load JS in head. That should solve your issue.

Comment: @Rajesh If that means putting the `<script>` tag in between `<head>` tags, then I already tried that.  It didn't work.

Comment: @chompy what is the error in that case?

Comment: @Rajesh No errors show up in the console.

Comment: @chompy I have added link of a fiddle in my answer. Please check. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you are getting error:

> gameTime.html:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSalaryZeroOrLess' of undefined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (gameTime.html:28)

because, you are trying to bind event in HTML

```html
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="fin.isSalaryZeroOrLess()">Submit</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gameTime.js"></script>
```

But as you see, your `gameTime.js` is not loaded yet. So `fin` is yet to be defined.

**Quick solution:**

Move your script tag to head.

**Robust solution**

Move event listeners to JS files and use `.addEventListener` and wrap your code in function(*IIFE*) so as to avoid polluting global scope.

---

I have updated your code and its working fine: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/tduocx3p/)**

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do that :)  But now I'm getting an error that says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at gameTime.js:31
    at gameTime.js:33`

Comment: If you notice, i have added id on button and fetching using it. You can use any mechanism to fetch element

Answer (score 0):

You don't ever invoke greaterThan function. You only define it and attach to Finance prototype, i don't see you ever doing something with it.

Comment: If you mean calling it, like so; `greaterThan();`.  I already tried that & it didn't work.  How do I invoke it?

Comment: You would simply do something like Finance.prototype.greatherThan();

Comment: Now i don't know when do you want to do this, i.e bind it to some event. I am not even getting into that now. Also you are getting the first error bacause fin is not defined at the time you are binding isSalaryZeroOrLess() function to onclick. Include your script in the head and it should be fine. This is very bad practice and you should not get used to writing js this way.

Comment: I see, that makes sense.  Thanks for the advice!